# How to convert column data type for data frames in a list with lapply?

Tags: r, list, data-cleaning

I have a list of data frames `allData`. Each data frame has a column called `idCode`. How do I change the type of `idCode` to character with lapply (or some other function if possible)?

I've tried this but it only returns me a list of all the "idCode" columns. Nothing changed in the original `allData` list.

```
lapply(allData, function(x) x$idCode <- as.character(x$idCode))
```

I've also tried this:

```
lapply(allData, function(x) {x$idCode <- as.character(x$idCode) x})
```

With the hope that it will return all the data frames with `idCode` converted, so I may "stitch" them together again in a new list. However, it give me an error: `unexpected symbol in "lapply(allData, function(x) {x$idCode <- as.character(x$idCode) x`.

Is it possible to do this with `lapply()`? Or some other functions are also OK.

Comment: `alldata[] <- lapply(allData, function(x) {x$idCode <- as.character(x$idCode); x})`

Comment: I find this one the simplest workable solution. Why the `[]` after `allData` though?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several options here:

You can just use a for loop and manipulate each dataframe with e.g. *as.character()*

```
for(i in 1:length(allData)){
      allData[[i]]$idCode<-as.character(allData[[i]]$idCode)
}
```

or you use the global variable assignement '<<-'

```
lapply(X = 1:length(allData),FUN = function(x){
      allData[[x]]$idCode<<-as.character(allData[[x]]$idCode)
      return(NULL)
})
```

In order to change the type of a column in a dataframe you can also use the function *class()*

```
lapply(X = 1:length(allData),FUN = function(x){
      class(allData[[x]]$idCode)<<-"character"
      return(NULL)
})
```